# Magento? Development Cycle

Tags: magento

How long does it usually take to develop a theme for magento? I'm considering venturing in learning [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com).

a week? a month?

Comment: What are you starting with? What are you going to end up with? What nonstandard widgets are you going to use and who will create them? How many of you are there? How often do you work? Estimating a development project requires more detail than "I'm using Magento". That said, I'm not sure this is really a programming question.

Comment: that's a mighty fine piece of string you got there, how long is it?

Comment: @joseph i'm taking this from a theoretical standpoint. Given you have all the tools necessary and that you're proficient. I just need advice from another developer's standpoint.  @jonathan thanks. that was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends how proficient you are with html, css, javascript and what tools you are using. I can tell that throughout planned theme will take a good slicer at least 2 days to master. Add the design time and usually it takes more time to design than to slice and dice it to end result.

If you have never used Magento before then it will take at least 6 months to become a somewhat good in designing and developing Magento in a way that it will take 2 days to output a theme

Answer (score 0):

I recently attended the UK Magento Meetup & there were a couple of presentations from Retailers & their implementation partners about creating multi-store Magento websites, especially creating new store fronts for different countries (English, French, etc)

In each presentation the design agencies reckoned it took 3-4 weeks to implement a new store front - I believe this included design & template creation (but may also have included time to do the translation files, etc).

What was certain, is that nobody appeared to be suggesting that a template could be knocked out & implemented within 2 days. You should think about spending 2 days just testing ....